# ExpressionEngine and subdomain issue

Tags: expressionengine

I'm new to ExpressionEngine but not to php so Im trying to work out if it is a quirk with EE, hosting issue or some config issue.

I'm in the process of developing a mobile version of a pre-existing EE site that was not developed by myself.

I've followed [this tutorial](http://erskinedesign.com/blog/create-an-alternative-version-of-your-expressionengine-website/) and [this tutorial](http://supergeekery.com/geekblog/comments/how_to_make_a_mobile_version_of_your_site_with_expression_engine_2) which has resulted in a mobile site that works apart from when you actually try to navigate anywhere apart from the index.

I get a 500 error if I visit the m. version of any link that would normally work with a www.

Could this be an open_basedir issue or a htaccess rewrite problem.

## SOLVED

It was my own stupidity and naievity with EE. I was using a index_test.php to do the initial testing just as I would do with Wordpress or any other thing I was developing. This seems to be a central location for how the whole system works and of course having the file name wrong meant that it through all links out of whack! Just didnt click!

Sorry for wasting everyones time...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How have you set up your subdomains in your host interface? Is the m. looking at the same public_html folder as the main site? Have you got any references to the full domain in htaccess?

Comment: Ok... it has its own public area that seems to be ok. I.e. the index works and grabs info correctly from the new mobile template. So I guess its kinda working. The htaccess has nothing special in it and tbh its just a direct copy of the primary site that deals with removing index.php

Comment: Think you need to include the index.php file from your mobile site and maybe the .htaccess for it in your question description. Have you added conditionals yet to EE templates to serve different content, or just getting the 2 domains working first?

Comment: Will do just gathering all the info to add to the post. Conditionals are all working well. I have a sneaking suspicion that its the htaccess but with no inkling to solving that.

Comment: Thanks Peter it was your 'include the index.php' that put me on the right path. Such a simple thing - overlooked by someone who has been doing this for long enough I should have known better.

Comment: Cool, half the time these things can be sorted just by talking it through to someone else, then the light bulb comes on! Might want to create the solution as an answer below, then mark it as correct so it completes the question better.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the index you are dealing with is actually 'index.php' and that it hasnt been renamed.

As the index.php is the core conduit for EE it makes sense that if this file is refereed to through the EE system and it cant be found a 500 error will be thrown...

Thanks to Peter!